# Symfony: Validation set in Constraints does not work

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

When I checked the operation of the app updated to Symfony 2.x-> Symfony 4.4, I found that the validation was not working well.
Even if the validation is set, even if you enter a value that is flipped by validation, it will not be flipped and will be saved.
Are there any changes in these features due to the Symfony update?

Html5EmailValidator.php

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class Html5EmailValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * @see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address
     * @see http://momdo.s35.xrea.com/web-html-test/spec/html5-dev/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address
     */
    const PATTERN = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if ($value === null || $value === '') {
            return;
        }

        if (!preg_match(self::PATTERN, $value, $matches)) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message);
        }
    }
}
```

Email.php

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * E-mail address constraint equivalent to HTML5 type = email check
 */
class Html5Email extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'This value is not a valid email address.';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'Html5Email';
    }
}
```

services.yaml

```yaml
    common.validator.html5EmailValidator:
        class: AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\Html5EmailValidator
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: Html5Email }
```

Staff.php

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use AppBundle\Model\Lib\Parameters;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Model\Repository\StaffRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="staff", uniqueConstraints={
 *      @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="idx_staff_unique", columns={"staff_login_id"}),
 *      @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="idx_image_mail_unique", columns={"image_mail"})
 * })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Staff implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable, EquatableInterface
{
    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="staff_mail", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, options={
     *      "comment"="staffmailaddress"
     * })
     */
    protected $staffMail;
    /**
     * Set staffMail
     *
     * @param string $staffMail
     * @return Staff
     */
    public function setStaffMail($staffMail)
    {
        $this->staffMail = $staffMail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get staffMail
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStaffMail()
    {
        return $this->staffMail;
    }
```

validation.yaml

```yaml
AppBundle\Model\Entity\Staff:
    constraints:
        - AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\Staff:
            groups: [hqNew, hqEdit]
    getters:
        staffMail:
            - Length: { max: 200, groups: [hqNew, hqInitialSetting, hqEdit] }
            - AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\Html5Email:
                groups: [hqNew, hqInitialSetting, hqEdit]
```

**Tried error**
Html5Email.php

```php
  /**
   * @Annotation
   */
  class Html5Email extends Constraint
  {
      public $message = 'This value is not a valid email address.';
  
     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
      public function validatedBy()
      {
          return 'AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\Html5EmailValidator';
      }
  }
```

Staff.php

```php
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\Html5Email as Html5Email;

      /*
       * @Html5Email
       * @ORM\Column(name="staff_mail", type="string", length=255, nullabl     e=true, options={
       *      "comment"="staffemailaddress"
       * })
       */
      protected $staffMail;
```

Comment: Can you show us how you use it in your entity ?

Comment: services.yaml declaration is not needed. What You need is just
`use App\Validator\Constraint as MyConstraint;` and  annotation `* @MyConstraint\UserPassword()`in Your Entity / field etc

Comment: @DylanKas I added Entity, so please check

Comment: @michal Thanks for your comment. When I searched for it, it was described in validation.yaml. Can you confirm it?

Comment: Yes @scottie320 it is described in yaml file by default in symfony config: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#using-the-new-validator but there is also tab in this listing to switch over to Annotations

Comment: @michal Thank you. I've tried the code, but it looks like the validation isn't working either.
I added the code I tried, so please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by changing to the following form.
Html5EmailValidator.php

```
        if (!preg_match(self::PATTERN, $value, $matches)) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                          ->addViolation();
        }
```